# Getting Data From IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have text file which contains airport Codes in this format:

```
"AAA","","Anaa Arpt","PF","","","AAA","2","N","272"
```

I used a `StreamReader` to to read the line from file and then I add that line to string list finally I convert that list to `IEnumerable` type.

Can you please help me how could I get only three values from each line for example

- `AAA` is airportCode
- `Anna Arpt` airport name
- `PF` is country Code

I want to get only these three values from each row.

Please find below the code.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/AirCodes/RAPT.TXT"))
{
    String line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        aircodesFromTravelPort.Add(line);
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
var codes = (IEnumerable<String>)aircodesFromTravelPort;
foreach (var aircode in codes)
```

Comment: A structured format like XML may make this easier

Comment: Search for "Parse CSV" to find solutions for this kind of problem.

Comment: ...but the nicest data format would be of course json ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can try using *Linq*, something like that:

```
  var codes = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:/AirCodes/RAPT.TXT")
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Select(items => new {
       // I've created a simple anonymous class, 
       // you'd probably want to create you own one
       Code = items[0].Trim('"'),    //TODO: Check numbers
       Airport = items[2].Trim('"'),
       Country = items[3].Trim('"')
    })
    .ToList();

  ...

  foreach(var item in codes) 
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: Use `ReadLines` rather than `ReadAllLines`. There's no reason to read the entire file into an array, just to discard it. `ReadLines` will read the file one line at a time, which means you'll be able to handle larger files.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to make use of String's `Split` function on each line to get the values into an array.

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  var values = line.Split(","); // here you have an array of strings containing the values between commas

  var airportCode = values[0];
  var airportName = values[2];
  var airportCountry = values[3]; 
  var airportInfo = airportCode + "," + airportName + "," + airportCountry;
  aircodesFromTravelPort.Add(airportInfo );
  // what you actually do with the values is up to you, I just tried to make it as close to the original as possible.

  Console.WriteLine(airportInfo);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I like `Regex` with named groups:

```
var line = @"""AAA"","""",""Anaa Arpt"",""PF"","""","""",""AAA"",""2"",""N"",""272""";
var pattern = @"^""(?<airportCode>\w+)"",""(\w*)"",""(?<ariportName>[\w\s]+)"",""(?<cuntryCode>\w+)""";
Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
    string airportCode = match.Groups["airportCode"].Value;
    string ariportName = match.Groups["ariportName"].Value;
    string cuntryCode = match.Groups["cuntryCode"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, because regex is so friggin cool that we have to use it even when something much simpler will work just fine.

Comment: of course ;-) - and the simple solution works as long as there are no other `,` commas ;-]

Comment: Well i used Linq to solve my problem thank you all for your support